# Bigger resistors in place of a level shifter on a SD reader?

Tags: sd, level-shifting

[This item](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/181211929705), a MMC/SD card reader module with 3V3 LDO and 10k pull-ups, has a schematic with an interesting tidbit in a big red box:

[image: SD card reader module]
[image: Second picture]

> Change R3, R4, R5, R6 resistance [from 2R7] to 330-470 [ohms], [then] you can use [it in a] 5V system

How can this be true? Is it wishful thinking, some part of the MMC/SD standard I don't know about, or something completely different?

Comment: That product page has all kinds of sketch suggestions, for example, that you can put 5V in place of +3V3 on that in pin 3 of J1, which means the card will be directly powered by 5V? I'm pretty sure that's a problem even if the bigger resistors somehow work...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that first one means that you have to put 5V on the connector and not in fact the pin, even though it points at the 3V3 pin.

Comment: Seems like they are relying on clamping diodes in the SD device and limiting the current with those resistors to make this work. This is *not* good design practice. Like at all.

Comment: Depends on the chip.  A number of manufacturers explicitly recommend this for their parts.

Comment: While I'm not aware of anything in a spec stating that these pins must have protection diodes capable of tolerating up to 5 mA, they are connectors *directly exposed to routine end-user handling* and so will probably be engineered with fairly robust ESD protection.

Answer (score 1):

The main question should be why use the resistors at all, rather than questioning the value change versus voltage.

Years ago I was using a 68HC711 SPI and a long cable run (5 feet). Operating at 5 volts. I was experiencing troubles with errors at a 500 kHz clock rate. I used 470 ohm resistors in SERIES with 3 lines (MISO, MOSI, SCK) also.

I put the resistors in series with the 3 lines because at the data rate I was running, this would reduce any reflections I might have in my pseudo transmission line, without destroying the square wave totally. I discovered this because when oscilloscope was connected that the SPI worked well.

I conclude that the resistors are not used as current limiting, rather they are for noise (reflections) suppression.

Comment: No, that is not the case in this type of application.  The notation is in explicit refernce to a voltage change, and matches common practice with many 3.3v parts.  The original 2R7 is too small to have much effect, and is probably chosen as an effective jumper that happened to be on hand.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the resistors could be used to take advantage of the SD cards internal clamping diodes. The resistors will limit the current through the clamping diodes in order not to damage them, and the diodes will clamp the data lines to just above the SD cards supply voltage. This would allow the 5V logic of the mcu to interface with the 3V3 logic of the SD.

Just my thoughts.... don't know if its true or not though..

Gavin

Comment: If you're not shure about the answer, this fit better as a comment.

Comment: @DanielGrillo, Gavin only has 1 rep, you need 30+ to make comments. It's silly, but I guess it avoids randoms comment-spamming until they are a little more settled into EE.SE

Comment: @Daniel - you are mistaken about the answer vs. comment criteria.  This is an answer.  It also happens to be true - though that is *not* a requirement.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I have reviewed my [criterias](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/151607) and I think you are right.